# What is wrong with the following implementation of the class AdvertisingSet in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, beacon

I am using BLE advertisement and scan for conducting some experiments by changing some of their parameters like transmission power etc. but it is not quite working.

The following implementation does not return anything and also doesn't give any kind of error so I am unable to identify where am I going wrong. I am new to the Bluetooth feature in android so any input will be extremely helpful.

Advertisement Code:

```
     private void transmit() {

    disableScanBtn();

    mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

    int advInterval;

    switch (advParameter){
        case 0 :
            advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_HIGH;
          
            break;

        case 1 :
            advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MEDIUM;
            
            break;
        case 2 :
            advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_LOW;
            
            break;
        case 3 :

            advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MIN;
            
            break;
        default:
            advInterval = AdvertisingSetParameters.INTERVAL_MAX;
            
    }
    AdvertisingSetParameters parameters = new AdvertisingSetParameters.Builder()
            .setInterval(advInterval)
            .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertisingSetParameters.TX_POWER_MEDIUM)
            .setConnectable(true)
            .build();
    ParcelUuid pUuid = new ParcelUuid( UUID.fromString( getString( R.string.ble_uuid ) ) );
    AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
            .setIncludeDeviceName(true)
            .addServiceUuid( pUuid )
            .addServiceData( pUuid, "Data".getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ) )
            .build();

    mAdvertiseCallback = new AdvertisingSetCallback () {

        @Override
        public void onAdvertisingSetStarted(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet,
                                            int txPower,
                                            int status) {
            super.onAdvertisingSetStarted (advertisingSet, txPower, status);
            Toast.makeText( BluetoothActivity.this, "Started "+ status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdvertisingSetStopped(AdvertisingSet advertisingSet) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Advertising onStartFailure: ");
            super.onAdvertisingSetStopped (advertisingSet);
        }
    };

    mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertisingSet(parameters, data, null,null,null, mAdvertiseCallback);
```

Comment: Let me understand your app has both scanning and advertising capabilities. Can as a client or server?

Comment: I have installed the app on two devices, one acts as a server and one as a client

Comment: Looks like your scanning app works, The advertising app is not working correct?

Comment: No I am not getting any result when I run it, do you get one? I want it advertise the device name,UUID and RSSI values, is the method I used correct?

Comment: Most of my Android BLE work is limited to scanning. I have not done any Android BLE transmitting app. I will be learning with you.